# Using map function to create React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I want to map over values and return an instance of my `<FirstRepeatAttributeLabelAssistant />` for every label (basically to render an label above each input, number of inputs can vary).

I've started off with this:

```
{object.attributeCollection.questions.map((question) => (
   <FirstRepeatAttributeLabelAssistant />
))}
```

The output of the map above is like so:

`[StringAttributeModel, MemoAttributeModel, LabelAttributeModel, MemoAttributeModel, StringAttributeModel, StringAttributeModel]` I only care about the "StringAttributeModel" as each of those 3 include 3 different labels (the part I care about). Their structure is like so:

[image]

How can I update my logic to ensure all of the potential labels are covered and a `<FirstRepeatAttributeLabelAssistant />` component is rendered for each of them?

Comment: What are the required props of `FirstRepeatAttributeLabelAssistant`? And what did you show in your console? Was it `object.attributeCollection.questions`?

Comment: it's probably just going to take a prop of: question={question}. The log of that question in the child component is all of the different objects

yeah object.attributeCollection.questions was what was shown in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose all your elements are a component, then you can simply do.

```
{object.attributeCollection.questions.map(Comp => {
  ...
  return <Comp label="..." />
})}
```

You can fill whatever your custom logic in the `...` area.